# Deleting modules from the database that aren't on the filesystem

Tags: 7

How do I remove modules that are referenced to in the database but have already been deleted from the filesystem?

This occurred because I had extra modules in my staging site, and I pushed the db to production. I would like to know how to clear out any modules from the db that aren't found on the filesystem.

Comment: Delete the related line in the system table, make sure you've cleared up any tables that the module installed (check the `hook_schema()` implementation in the .install file for details). Then clear the caches. That should be all you need to do, but always test on a dev copy first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Schema](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema) module.

This module compares the live database structure with the schema structure declared by all enabled modules, reporting
on any missing or incorrect tables

> The Schema module provides additional Schema-related functionality not provided by the core Schema API that is useful for module developers. Currently, this includes:
>
> - Schema documentation: hyperlinked display of the schema's embedded    documentation explaining what each table and field is for.
> - Schema structure generation: the module examines the live database    and creates Schema API data structures for all tables that match the
>     live database.
> - Schema comparison: the module compares the live database structure    with the schema structure declared by all enabled modules, reporting
>     on any missing or incorrect tables.

Comment: Thank you! Schema > Compare > Extra showed me a bunch of `feeds_*` tables, which I dropped. Then I could clear the performance cache without getting a PHP error from missing modules.